# i am using "ng-multiselect-dropdown" but when i select list selected values is shown in input side of dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, drop-down-menu

> This is html of multiselect-dropdownList
> i am using "ng-multiselect-dropdown" but when i select list selected values is shown in input side of dropdown

```
  <div class="multiselect-dropdownList">
    <[![ng-multiselect-dropdown][1]][1]
     required 
        name="city"
        [placeholder]="'VendorList'"
        [data]="designerList"
        [settings]="dropdowDesiner"
        (onSelect)="onChangeDesignerList($event)"
        (onSelectAll)="onChangeDesignerList($event)"
        (onDeSelect)="onChangeDesignerList($event)"
        (onDropDownClose)="onDropDownClose()"
        
        >
      </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: are you using [this](https://github.com/NileshPatel17/ng-multiselect-dropdown) component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If You are using ng-multiselect-dropdown then all records must be show in input
  field
- You can use css to hide this.
  eg
  .ng-select /deep/ select-dropdown .selected {
  display: none
  }

Answer (score 0):

you can bind a variable, which contains elements you want to preselect, something like this:

```
equals(objOne, objTwo) {
    if (typeof objOne !== 'undefined' && typeof objTwo !== 'undefined') {
      return objOne.id === objTwo.id;
    }
}
selectAll(checkAll, select: NgModel, values) {
    //this.toCheck = !this.toCheck;
    if(checkAll){
      select.update.emit(values); 
    }
    else{
      select.update.emit([]);
    }
  }
```

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedYears" [compareWith]="equals"  [multiple]= true
```

And then you can just filter your initial array of items and get only those, which you want to select by default (it should be stored in selection class property in provided case).

Answer (score 0):

I have used the disabled:true property to disable it and to hide the dropdown I have used the class
`.multiselect-dropdown { .dropdown-list { display: none !important; } }`